# How do I fuzz a stdarg.h function?

Tags: c, variadic-functions, fuzzing

I've written a function similar to printf in operation, and I want to fuzz it to check for bugs. afl-fuzz gives me a input file, but I'm struggling to think of a way to turn this into varargs input.

Is there any way to dynamically construct a va_list or otherwise dynamically construct the argument list?

Comment: Maybe [libffi](https://github.com/libffi/libffi), the [Foreign Function Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libffi) library.

Comment: @Jonathan That sounds like an idea, I'll look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[dyncall](http://www.dyncall.org/) appears to have been written to do what you want, although I have not personally used it.

An alternative approach would be to generate source code that calls the function in question with a lot of inputs. It is much less elegant, but It should be straightforward to program.

Answer (score 0):

libffi can be used to assemble arguments to variadic functions and call them.

Specifically, the `ffi_prep_cif_var` function needs to be used: https://github.com/libffi/libffi/blob/master/doc/libffi.texi#L152-L153